# Remove empty categories from xml sitemap

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, seo, sitemaps

My xml site map is showing categories which contain no products (although some child categories may). Is there a simple way of removing these from the xml or do I need to count products as magento loops through the category tree?

Answer (score 2):

To do it, we need rewrite two classes:

### 1. Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Abstract

The `_addFilter` method will be responsible to filter our category collection. But `_addFilter` has just to condition filter: `equal` and `in`:

```
protected function _addFilter($storeId, $attributeCode, $value, $type = '=')
{
    [...]

    switch ($type) {
        case '=':
            $conditionRule = '=?';
            break;
        case 'in':
            $conditionRule = ' IN(?)';
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    [...]
```

So, we need do a new conditionRule to get category with a count greater than zero:

```
protected function _addFilter($storeId, $attributeCode, $value, $type = '=')
{
    [...]

    switch ($type) {
        case '=':
            $conditionRule = '=?';
            break;
        case 'in':
            $conditionRule = ' IN(?)';
            break;
        case '>': // Our new case here
            $conditionRule = '>?';
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    [...]
```

### 2. Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Catalog_Category

Now we just need filter our collection in `getCollection`:

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    [...]

    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'is_active', 1);

    /* HERE YOU WILL PUT A NEW FILTER */
    $this->_addFilter($storeId, 'children_count', 0, '>');

    return $this->_loadEntities();
}
```

Note: Don't hack the core, build a extension to rewrite it.

Note2: I tested it. It works.